# How to navigate back to the Java appliacation from a web page in Browser Session?

Tags: javascript, browser, blackberry

We are developing a Java application for BlackBerry. We have the home screen in which we have various links to open the different versions of the news pages. We have links in these news pages to open the various articles. We need to create a href link in the web page which should act like the home button. When the user clicks on this home button, the application should navigate back to the Home screen. The web pages arer being created by us. So, we can embed any code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have same problem, but i m even not able to implement BrowserContentProvider in my application. Can you please help me. Can you share code of ur application. Please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This took me awhile to figure out and to get working, but once I did, the concept seemed so simple. Look into BrowserContentProvider. If my memory serves, you can find an example of this in the SDK. Essentially, you can register a BrowserContentProvider with your application. Then, you set up your website link with a certain extension. When the BlackBerry browser doesn't know how to handle that extension, it will go around and "ask" if any other applications know how to handle it. Your application can then recognize it and request the foreground (to open on top of the browser).

Comment: Hi littlek,
It is working fine and we are getting the function call to our application. But we are not able to push our application in to the foreground. Please advise us in this regard.
Thanks.